# angular cli error while creating new project

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular

While creating new project with angular cli, with command

```
ng new <project_name>
```

I am getting following error

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ae0e20ec","tarball":"'
```

I tried executing the ng command with sudo acces, but still I get the same error.
I am currently having, angular

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.8
Node: 10.19.0
OS: linux x64
```

And

```
NPM - 6.14.4
```

Comment: tryo to clean your npm cache with : `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: That's a really old version of node and I don't think it's supported anymore

Comment: sorry,  thats npm version, node version is 10.19.0

Answer (score 0):

try the below step, and try again

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: i have tried it, but still i am getting the same error

Comment: try this ==> 
npx -p @angular/cli@8 ng new myAPP

Comment: Maybe you should upgrade your Nodejs version, you can check this gist https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3 to choose the right version of nodejs to set up correctly your angular application